# IP address of client in Python SimpleXMLRPCServer?

Tags: python, ip-address, xml-rpc, simplexmlrpcserver

I have a [SimpleXMLRPCServer](http://docs.python.org/library/simplexmlrpcserver.html#SimpleXMLRPCServer.SimpleXMLRPCServer) server (Python).

How can I get the IP address of the client in the request handler?

This information appears in the log. However, I am not sure how to access this information from within the request handler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Michael noted, you can get `client_address` from within the request handler. For instance, you can override the `__init__` function which is inherited indirectly from `BaseRequestHandler`.

```
class RequestHandler(SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, request, client_address, server):
        print client_address # do what you need to do with client_address here
        SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler.__init__(self, request, client_address, server)
```

Answer (score 3):

The request handler itself should have a property `client_address` (inherited from `BaseHTTPRequestHandler`). From [BaseHTTPRequestHandler](http://docs.python.org/library/basehttpserver.html#BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

> Contains a tuple of the form `(host, port)` referring to the client’s address.

Comment: How do I access the RequestHandler from within the request method itself? There is no self parameter.

Answer (score 2):

One way to pass the ip address to the request method is to override RequestHandler.decode_request_content.

decode_request_content returns a XML string.
Example:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<methodCall>
    <methodName>get_workunit</methodName>
    <params>
        <param>
            <value><int>1</int></value>
        </param>
        <param>
            <value><string>Windows</string></value>
        </param>
        <param>
            <value><string>32bit</string></value>
        </param>
    </params>
</methodCall>
```

Just slip another parameter in there.

```
class HackyRequestHandler(SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, req, addr, server):
       self.client_ip, self.client_port = addr
       SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler.__init__(self, req, addr, server)
    def decode_request_content(self, data):
       data = SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler.decode_request_content(self, data)
       from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
       doc = parseString(data)
       ps = doc.getElementsByTagName('params')[0]
       pdoc = parseString(
            ''' <param><value>
                <string>%s</string>
                </value></param>''' % (self.client_ip,))
       p = pdoc.firstChild.cloneNode(True)
       ps.insertBefore(p, ps.firstChild)
       return doc.toxml()
```

and update your method signatures accordingly.